Can't start Steam game from cmdline - existing file does not exist
I can start the game via Steam normally without problems. But I want to start a script instead which will launch the game.
Steam logs a command to syslog like this:
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=56400 -- /home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/compatibilitytools.d/GE-Proton8-11'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Dawn of War II - Retribution/DOW2.exe'\0

After quoting I run:
/bin/sh -c "/home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=56400 -- /home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kuba/.local/share/Steam/compatibilitytools.d/GE-Proton8-11'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Dawn of War II - Retribution/DOW2.exe'"

But I get an error:
pressure-vessel-adverb[175960]: E: Failed to execute child process "/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper/pressure-vessel/bin/steam-runtime-launcher-interface-0" (No such file or directory)

The crazy thing is that file does exist!
that_cmd 2>&1 | grep -o '".*"' | xargs file
/games/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper/pressure-vessel/bin/steam-runtime-launcher-interface-0: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=f9f3879d7dc5c745fe91e9c7fcbd4f4e37dc5f35, stripped

What should I put in Launch options to start a script that will be able to start the game?

how did you install steam? and what os are you on?

@killertofus Linux and Steam is natively installed. It has the button to show only Linux games.
